# Define relationships for 3 tables

Tags: sql-server-express

I have 3 tables that are currently defined as:

[image: Current Rleationship]

Is this the best way, or should I use an associative table?

I put the relationships backwards, 1 group can contain many users and many students.  There is no other relationship between the user and the student other than the group.  This is for a tracking program where the user or users are taking a student or group of students through a check-in procedure.

Comment: With this model a Group can only have one User and one Student.  Is that correct? Or do you, as I suspect, want a group to be able to contain many users and many students?  Perhaps expand on what you need to be able to show.  Im also a little perplexed by the distinction of Users and Students. Can a Student have many Users?

Comment: Thanks, I tend to put the notations backwards.  While I didn't fix the image hopefully the clarification will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description you want to have a `GroupMembers` table that does all the many to many joins for you.

Your current schema only allows a `Group` to contain one `User` and one `Student` as you have made the GroupName the Primary Key.  You really want to break the `Group` out to its own table in case the group name changes.

This can allow you to have:

- A `Group` with many `Users` and many `Students`
- `Users` can be members of many `Groups`
- `Students` can be members of many `Group`
- A `User` should not be duplicated in a `Group`
- A `Student` should not be duplicated in a `Group`

Thats achieved with a schema like this:

[image]

Because you only ever want one combination of a given group, user and student you can make the foreign key columns the primary key too.

This all follows [Third Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (at least).

Comment: That is kind of what I was thinking, but as I'm still relatively inexperienced with relational databases I wanted to get clarification.  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: If the above doesnt answer your question; please feel free to ask via a comment or update your original question and I'll amend.